# Modify Arduino Code to Work With NodeMCU ESP-12e

Tags: c++, arduino, wifi, sensors, esp8266

I found this great library on [Github](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050/examples) which contains links to use a MPU-6050 gyro/accelerometer with arduino and he has an example in there where he uses it for an esp module and just a normal arduino. The esp library does not work for me but in the tutorial where I found the github they show the library called "MPU6050_DMP6_using_DMP_V6.12" working. Since i cannot fix the library for the esp and I cannot find another library online which uses this module and implements the Interrupt key, which I need for my janky-VR controller project, I was wondering if there was a way to edit the code in the previsoudly mentioned sketch to work with the esp. The problem I have with the old esp sketch is that nothing shows up to serial moniter even though I have the baud rate correct on everything. Maybe if you guys could figure out a way to implement it to work with the esp then that would be amazing as I cannot figure out his code. Here is a project I managed to get displaying to serial yet does not utilize the Interrupt key, if this might be helpfull.

```
#include <Wire.h>

// MPU6050 Slave Device Address
const uint8_t MPU6050SlaveAddress = 0x68;

// Select SDA and SCL pins for I2C communication 
const uint8_t scl = D6;
const uint8_t sda = D7;

// sensitivity scale factor respective to full scale setting provided in datasheet 
const uint16_t AccelScaleFactor = 16384;
const uint16_t GyroScaleFactor = 131;

// MPU6050 few configuration register addresses
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_SMPLRT_DIV   =  0x19;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_USER_CTRL    =  0x6A;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_PWR_MGMT_1   =  0x6B;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_PWR_MGMT_2   =  0x6C;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_CONFIG       =  0x1A;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_GYRO_CONFIG  =  0x1B;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_ACCEL_CONFIG =  0x1C;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_FIFO_EN      =  0x23;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_INT_ENABLE   =  0x38;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_ACCEL_XOUT_H =  0x3B;
const uint8_t MPU6050_REGISTER_SIGNAL_PATH_RESET  = 0x68;

int16_t AccelX, AccelY, AccelZ, Temperature, GyroX, GyroY, GyroZ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin(sda, scl);
  MPU6050_Init();
}

void loop() {
  double Ax, Ay, Az, T, Gx, Gy, Gz;

  Read_RawValue(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_ACCEL_XOUT_H);

  //divide each with their sensitivity scale factor
  Ax = (double)AccelX/AccelScaleFactor;
  Ay = (double)AccelY/AccelScaleFactor;
  Az = (double)AccelZ/AccelScaleFactor;
  T = (double)Temperature/340+36.53; //temperature formula
  Gx = (double)GyroX/GyroScaleFactor;
  Gy = (double)GyroY/GyroScaleFactor;
  Gz = (double)GyroZ/GyroScaleFactor;

  Serial.print("Ax: "); Serial.print(Ax);
  Serial.print(" Ay: "); Serial.print(Ay);
  Serial.print(" Az: "); Serial.print(Az);
  Serial.print(" T: "); Serial.print(T);
  Serial.print(" Gx: "); Serial.print(Gx);
  Serial.print(" Gy: "); Serial.print(Gy);
  Serial.print(" Gz: "); Serial.println(Gz);

  delay(100);
}

void I2C_Write(uint8_t deviceAddress, uint8_t regAddress, uint8_t data){
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress);
  Wire.write(regAddress);
  Wire.write(data);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

// read all 14 register
void Read_RawValue(uint8_t deviceAddress, uint8_t regAddress){
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress);
  Wire.write(regAddress);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(deviceAddress, (uint8_t)14);
  AccelX = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  AccelY = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  AccelZ = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  Temperature = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  GyroX = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  GyroY = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
  GyroZ = (((int16_t)Wire.read()<<8) | Wire.read());
}

//configure MPU6050
void MPU6050_Init(){
  delay(150);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_SMPLRT_DIV, 0x07);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_PWR_MGMT_1, 0x01);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_PWR_MGMT_2, 0x00);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_CONFIG, 0x00);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_GYRO_CONFIG, 0x00);//set +/-250 degree/second full scale
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_ACCEL_CONFIG, 0x00);// set +/- 2g full scale
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_FIFO_EN, 0x00);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_INT_ENABLE, 0x01);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_SIGNAL_PATH_RESET, 0x00);
  I2C_Write(MPU6050SlaveAddress, MPU6050_REGISTER_USER_CTRL, 0x00);
}
```

Edit: here is the board setup im using along with the ["MPU6050_DMP6_ESPWiFi"](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050/examples/MPU6050_DMP6_ESPWiFi) example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. check the I2C interface is working or not using **I2C_Scanner** example. Which will return the address of the I2C devices connected. 
   If Address returns then it is confirm that I2C is working.
2. Check if you have connected pull up resistors.
3. You can reconfirm your serial connection. Just comment **Wire.begin(sda, scl);** call.
4. try to use default i2c pins.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! While im sure your comment is helpfull, I cannot understand it. Although I do know how to write c++ code and use the arduino IDE, i did not write this example myself. I know that when reffering to the i2c pins you mean the slave and master between the board and the SCL and SDA pins, yet I know little more. If you could simplify these instructions or link me to an article which could provide further resource that would be much apprecaited! Thanks! :)

Comment: which arduino board are you using? If you see board pin layout there will pins with name as SDA and SCL. These two pins are i2c pins. Connect your i2c device (MPU-6050 gyro/accelerometer) to these pins.

Comment: I will update my post to show the board setup I currently have in accordance with the esp script in the mentioned github repo